# Copy/Paste remove duplicates/blanks: Array Column

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

This issue is related with VBA. Involves copy and paste data (unique values, formatting and exclude blanks).

**What I have:**
1 sheet (DB) with different headers, and then I've the data below (can be numbers or strings or blanks).

**What I want:**
Have in another sheet (Destination) with the unique values of some columns from the data source but without data formatting and without blanks.

**My idea:**

1. **Copy** the specific columns I want in DB sheet and **paste** into Destination sheet (specific columns as well). Always following the 1 column in origin to 1 column in the destination. Paste as values.
2. Select the columns in Destination sheet and **remove duplicates**
3. Select the columns in Destination sheet and **remove blanks** (also **ascending sorting** would work as the blanks would be moved to the end)

**Code:**

```
Sub Clean_Data()

Dim arr1, arr2, i As Integer
Dim LastNRow As Long
'Get the last used cell within the sheet (column in use A to L only) in order to capture the last row
With Sheets("DB")
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then 'Select the Column Range below
        LastNRow = .Range("A:L").Find(What:="*", _
              After:=.Range("A1"), _
              Lookat:=xlPart, _
              LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
              MatchCase:=False).Row
    Else
        LastNRow = 1 'This won't ever happen
End If

    arr1 = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "G", "H", "I", "J", "L") 'copy these columns in DB
    arr2 = Array("A", "D", "G", "J", "M", "P", "S", "V", "Y") 'paste into these columns in Destination

    For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
        With Sheets("DB")    
            .Range(.Cells(2, arr1(i)), .Cells(LastNRow, arr1(i))).Copy
            Sheets("Destination").Range(arr2(i) & 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End With
    Next

'remove the duplicates
    For i = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
        With Sheets("Destination")
            .Range(.Cells(3, arr2(i)), .Cells(LastNRow, arr1(i))).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo
        End With
     Next

'remove the blank (I tried to use the sorting methodology as I couldn't figure out any code to remove the blanks/empty)
    For i = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
        With Sheets("Destination")
            .Range(.Cells(2, arr1(i)), .Cells(LastNRow, arr1(i))).Sort key1:=Array(1), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
        End With
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End With

End Sub
```

**Problems:**

1. The remove blanks/empty code isn't working (I tried to adopt the ascending sorting methodology), but still couldn't figure out what is wrong.
2. Is there a way to remove duplicates and sort in the same code group? instead of opening again the "With" and "End With".

Thank you very much for your time and for your help

I included all the code because it may be useful for someone else who is trying to do similar thing.

Have a great day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple of issues with your code:

1) Don't use sorting for removing blank cells from a range. Excel has a native function for that.

2) Name your arrays more reader-friendly, so you don't confuse the source sheet with the destination sheet.

3) When writing to the document, set `ScreenUpdating` to `False`, so the code runs faster.

This works for me:

```
Sub removeDuplicatesAndBlankCells()

    Dim i As Long, LastNRow As Long
    Dim tmpRng As Range
    Dim arrDestSheet As Variant, arrSourceSheet As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Get the last used cell within the sheet (column in use A to L only) in order to capture the last row
    With Sheets("DB")
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then 'Select the Column Range below
            LastNRow = .Range("A:L").Find(What:="*", _
                  After:=.Range("A1"), _
                  Lookat:=xlPart, _
                  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                  MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            LastNRow = 1 'This won't ever happen
    End If

    arrSourceSheet = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "G", "H", "I", "J", "L") 'copy these columns in DB
    arrDestSheet = Array("A", "D", "G", "J", "M", "P", "S", "V", "Y") 'paste into these columns in Destination

    ' copy column content
    For i = LBound(arrSourceSheet) To UBound(arrSourceSheet)
        With Sheets("DB")
            .Range(.Cells(2, arrSourceSheet(i)), .Cells(LastNRow, arrSourceSheet(i))).Copy
            Sheets("Destination").Range(arrDestSheet(i) & 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End With
    Next

     ' remove blank cells
    For i = LBound(arrDestSheet) To UBound(arrDestSheet)
        With Sheets("Destination")
            Set tmpRng = .Range(.Cells(2, arrDestSheet(i)), .Cells(LastNRow, arrDestSheet(i)))
            tmpRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete
        End With
    Next

    ' remove duplicates
    For i = LBound(arrDestSheet) To UBound(arrDestSheet)
        With Sheets("Destination")
            .Range(.Cells(2, arrDestSheet(i)), .Cells(LastNRow, arrDestSheet(i))).removeDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo
        End With
    Next

    End With

    With Application
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Miqi180, thank you very very much for your help in the code improvement and solution on the issues. The code works well.
But, how can I make the remove blank cells 
 " SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete " instead of moving to the left, move up? 
Thank you once again

Comment: @Miqui180 I just miss clicked and deleted the previous question, my question is in that part (remove blank/empty cells) indeed.
Thanks

Comment: Miqui180, I just tried with the following code: SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp

It works, but I don't know why, in 2 columns the pasted data includes 2 blank/empty cells, it's quite strange. There's no space, neither formulas.

Comment: Great it worked. I can't give you a good explanation as to why it was necessary for you to include `Shift:=xlUp`. It certainly wasn't when I tested the code. However, you might consider clearing the contents of the destination sheet before inserting the data if the code is to be run several times on the same source sheets.

Comment: Miqi180, no worries, was just a small detail, as the data was shifting to the left side. it's solved now, and I really appreciated your help.
Cheers :)