# Remove duplicate values and cells from one column

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I have tried so many methods from the removeduplicates, selections and scripting dictionaries and I cannot get this to work.  I do understand there are multiple ways to do this but if any of you can help, that would be great.

I have one list of values that I am pulling through from another sheet (up to approx 80k rows) into cell B13 downwards.  I am then trying to remove the duplicate values and cells so I am left with unique values which I can then use to perform lookups on other sheets.

```
Sub Address_Sage()

    Dim dataBook As Workbook
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim Sage_Data As Worksheet, Address As Worksheet
    Dim dataSource As Range, dataDest As Range
    Dim sourceDataRowCount As Integer, index As Integer
    Dim rowCount As Long
    Dim strVal As String

    Set dataBook = Application.ThisWorkbook
    Set sheetSource = dataBook.Sheets("Sage_Data")
    Set sheetDest = dataBook.Sheets("Address")
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set dataSource = sheetSource.Range("A3", _
                    sheetSource.Range("A90000").End(xlUp))
    sourceDataRowCount = dataSource.Rows.Count

    Set dataDest = sheetDest.Range("B13", "B" & _
                                sourceDataRowCount)

    For index = 1 To sourceDataRowCount
      dataDest(index, 1).Value = dataSource(index, 1).Value
    Next index

    Sheets("Address").Select

    rowCount = ActiveSheet.Range("B13").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    Do While rowCount > 0
      strVal = Address.Cells(rowCount, 1).Value2

      If dict.exists(strVal) Then
        ActiveSheet.Rows(rowCount).EntireRow.Delete
      Else
        dict.Add strVal, 0
      End If

      rowCount = rowCount - 1
    Loop
    'Set dict = Nothing

End Sub
```

It always gets stuck on `strVal` line.  I have tried changing `value2` to `value1` as I only have column but no luck.

thank you

Comment: Why don't you use the [Range.RemoveDuplicates Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-removeduplicates-method-excel)? Should be easier than re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: From reading through the various solutions, it appeared that the scripting dictionary was a better solution for this.  I did get it to run but it didn't run correctly, left blank rows and took considerable time to run.

Comment: Why do you think it is better than RemoveDuplicates? This was invented exactly for that purpose by Microsoft. Did you have any issues with RemoveDuplicates?

Comment: Yes, it didn't run correctly (it removed values that were not duplicates), left blank rows (where it had removed values) and took considerable time  to run.

Comment: well if it removed values that were not duplicates you must have done something wrong. And yes 80k Values will always take some time (even your loop will need it). • Nevertheless if you need help with your code you must explain what is going wrong. What errors do you get and where. Also it is unclear in which column the duplicate values are.

Comment: I agree that using the native functions for this is preferable and that you must have miscoded when you tried `RemoveDuplicates` the first time. Anyway, your question is very similar to this one, which has a solution that works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50525932/copy-paste-remove-duplicates-blanks-array-column/50528666#50528666

Comment: Agree with previous comments. However, you declare `Address` as a worksheet variable but you never define it (not good choice for a name btw as it's an VBA property but may not prevent your code from working). The 2 in `value2` has nothing to do with column numbers and there is no `value1` property (afaik).

Comment: Thank you for all the comments, have changed back to removeduplicates, have also changed the sheetname from address and I have it working.  When I get chance I'll take a better look at scripting dictionaries... thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not super experienced in VBA so I can't speak to exactly what you're doing and what your code is saying but I thought I'd share this with you. Last week I had to create a macrobook that returned the unique entries of electrical defects that different crews observed while on the job. I made a dictionary that read all of the entries in the spreadsheet and then later printed all of the unique entries. I'll post the code and try to walk you through it.

```
If .Range("A" & i) <> "" Then
    If dict.Exists(data) Then
        dict(data) = dict(data) + 1
    Else
        dict.Add Key:=Data, Item:="1"
    End If
End If
```

So the code basically says if column A (i is simply an incrementer) is not empty, then we're going to read the entries of column A. Data is simply a variable and you would set it equal to the range of values you'd like read in the dictionary. Obviously dictionary keys are unique and cannot repeat, so the code asks if the key already exists in the dictionary. If so, we will add one to it's count or value. And if not we will add that key to the dictionary. At the end of your loop, your dictionary will have stored all unique entries and the number of times they appeared.

Now we can reference them or print them.

```
For r = 0 To dict.Count
    Sheets("Results").Range("B" & iResults) = dict.Keys(r)
    Sheets("Results").Range("C" & iResults) = dict(dict.Keys(r))
Next
```

This second piece of code is a loop from 0 to the number of entries in your dictionary. It starts at zero because the dictionary is stored like an array and VBA arrays are base zero. The first statement will print the unique keys for every r until there are no more entries in the dictionary. The second statement will print the value or items associated with them. It will be an integer value equal to the number of times that unique entry showed up in your data.

You can use this same method for other purposes as well, not just printing the data but referencing it and using it somewhere else. But I am sure you will find that the For-loop with dict.Keys(r) is the easiest way to run through your dictionary entries. Took me a few days to figure it out and it revolutionized my program. Hope this helps you out.